# API to support Bluetooth in Mango?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bluetooth, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

Will there be an API in the upcoming Mango that provides access to devices coupled via Bluetooth? I am interested in processing data sent from Polar Hear Rate Monitoring belt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding API information won't become fully known until the tools are released next week alongside the updated tools and emulator. I'd suggest waiting until then to review exactly what APIs have been added and what the scope of those new APIs are.

Comment: The tools should hit on May 24th, just in case anyone was looking for a date.

Answer (score 2):

Shawn Oster advised at Mix11 that the answer is no to bluetooth API support in the Mango SDK at this stage. It's been a hotly requested topic, so I'm not sure what the blocker is on this.

Stay tuned for the tools to drop this month for updates.

Refer to 56:50 in DVC15 from Mix11 to catch this, the latest advice, from Shawn.